# Error when creating new C# project with C# dev kit

Tags: c#, vscode-extensions

When I try to create a new project with the C# dev kit extension for VS Code, I get the error

> command 'csdevkit.addNewProject' not found

[image: The error]

I'm not sure what to do because it seems like nobody else has ever had this problem. I have a feeling this might be a linux issue. I'm using Debian 12.

Comment: As a side note: VS Code is just a toy for C# language, use more serious and well tested reliable tools for backend C# development: Rider, for example, or Visual Studio (on Windows). Actually i had the same issue, just ignored it, creating project with `dotnet new` command.

Comment: @Ryan - I'm not sure I'd characterize VSCode as "just a toy".  But I agree that any "serious" C# development merits using an IDE like MSVS.  And `dotnet new` is probably an excellent workaround for the OP's issue ("command 'csdevkit.addNewProject' not found")

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error appears on my Windows 11 machine. Found this issue on official GitHub repo:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dotnettools/issues/225

I solved following what webreidi user said:
*"Can you look at the C# extension? In order for C# Dev Kit to work, it requires the prerelease version (>2.0). You can get that version by clicking the "Switch to prerelease" button at the top of the C# extension page."*

Comment: You also need to be on the pre-release version of C# (as of Jul 19th '23) as well. I'm getting another error though -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76720485/vs-code-error-when-creating-a-new-maui-project